# Getting rid of repeating parts of code in Activities

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm new to Android, so at some point I realized that I have 20 Activities with same parts in them.

The whole;e structure of app is the following:
Activity1 -> Activity2 -> TaskActivity1 -> Activity3 -> Activity4 -> TaskActivity2 -> ...

So, there 2 types of repeating code: for simple Activities and for task Activities.

Providing code for simple Activities:

```
class Activity2 : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2)
}

fun nextClick(view: View, ID: Int) {
    val intent3 = Intent(this, Activity3::class.java)
    startActivity(intent3)
    this.finish()
}

fun backClick(view: View){
    val intent1 = Intent(this, Activity1::class.java)
    startActivity(intent1)
    this.finish()
}
```

}

With tasks, only 3 more buttons (for answers) are added (so, there 5 of them: next, ans1, ans2, ans3, back). Also, some of simple Activities do not have back button in layout.

So, obviously I have about 15 activities with the same code (and it looks awful).

I tried:

1) Creating a class for activities:

```
open class everyActivity(imageId: Int, nextActivity: Activity, prevActivity: Activity): AppCompatActivity() {

val imageId = imageId
val nextActivity = nextActivity
val prevActivity = prevActivity

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(imageId)
}

fun nextClick(view: View) {
    val intentNext = Intent(this, nextActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intentNext)
    this.finish()
}

fun backClick(view: View){
    val intentPrev = Intent(this, prevActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intentPrev)
    this.finish()
}
```

}

And then in Activity:

```
class Kadr1Activity : KadrActivity(R.layout.activity_kadr01, Kadr2Activity(), Kadr0InfoActivity()) {
}
```

It does not work, the app shows white screen.

2) Extracting functions for Clicks:

It's impossible to pass Activity variable in onClick, so Extracting functions doesn't help.

3) Sticking to 1 Activity:

I do not want to just change ImageView picture with every click. As I've already mentioned, some Activities look differently (with no back button), so keeping track of changing buttons depending on the current image is not convenient.

4) Single Activity Architecture

I want to have animation between activities and with fragments it is too complicated (according to the information I've found).

**So, is it possible to get rid of repeating code in my app?**

Would be grateful for any possible help, have no idea how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

If I couldn't just swap fragments and *had* to do separate Activities, I would make a single Activity class and open multiple instances of it, using Intent extras to determine the slight differences in behavior, like this:

```
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity()

    private val screen by lazy { 
        Screen.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra(SCREEN_KEY) ?: Screen.SCREEN_ONE.name)
        // The Elvis operator is to specifiy the default for when the activity
        // is the first instance from when the app was launched.
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity)
        imageView.setImageResource(screen.imageID)

        prepareButton(previousButton, Screen[screen.prevScreen])
        prepareButton(nextButton, Screen[screen.nextScreen])
    }

    private fun prepareButton(button: Button, targetScreen: Screen?) {
        if (targetScreen == null) {
            button.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        } else {
            button.setOnClickListener { 
                val intent = Intent(this, MyActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(SCREEN_KEY, targetScreen.name)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
           }
        }
    }
}

private const SCREEN_KEY = "SCREEN"

enum class Screen(val imageID: Int, val prevScreen: String?, val nextScreen: String?) {
    SCREEN_ONE(R.drawable.screenOneImg, null, "SCREEN_TWO"),
    SCREEN_TWO(R.drawable.screenTwoImg, "SCREEN_ONE", "SCREEN_THREE"),
    SCREEN_THREE(R.drawable.screenThreeImg, "SCREEN_TWO", null)

    companion object {
        operator fun get(name: String?) = name?.let { Screen.valueOf(it) }
    }
}
```

Note for simplicity the above sample code is written as if you're using synthetic view properties. If you're not, you would be using `findViewById` or view binding to get the view references.

---

Edit:

Here's a more beginner-friendly way to do it without an enum or lazy property:

```
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity()

    companion object {
        private const SCREEN_KEY = "SCREEN"
        private const lastScreenIndex = 2 // if there are three screens (counting starts at 0)
    }

    private var screen: Int = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity)

        screen = intent.getStringExtra(SCREEN_KEY) ?: 0 // 0 is default screen number
        val screenImageResource = when (screen) {
            0 -> R.drawable.screen_0_image
            1 -> R.drawable.screen_1_image
            else -> R.drawable.screen_2_image
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(screenImageResource )

        prepareScreen(previousButton, screen - 1)
        prepareScreen(nextButton, screen + 1)
    }

    private fun prepareButton(button: Button, targetScreen: Int) {
        if ((0..lastScreenIndex).contains(targetScreen)) {
            button.setOnClickListener { 
                val intent = Intent(this, MyActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(SCREEN_KEY, targetScreen)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
           }
        } else {
            button.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I tried to understand the idea, your solution seems to be too complex for me. Neither can I get the idea, nor implement it in my app. But I am still trying to make it work. The main problem: cannot figure out how to use getExtra as there seems to be no such function.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `getStringExtra()`. Sorry if this is kind of complicated. The enum is just one way to store the set of possibilities in a concise way.

Comment: I added a different way to do it without using enums or lazy properties.